# Append One string from each text file back and forth in batch file

Tags: string, append

I am trying to create a batch file which will append a line from two or three separate files back and forth.

It's hard to explain and even harder to search for.

An Example:

---

### IP.txt:

192.168.0.1
159.258.25.25
12.1.1.1 
123.23.25.25

### Int.txt:

int gig1/1
int gig2/2
int gig1/3
int gig2/3

### Des.txt

Description uplink to router
Description uplink to switch
Description uplink to user
Description uplink to server

these are just made up, however you get the point.

I would like to append so it comes out as:

### Exmple:

192.168.0.1
int gig1/1
Description uplink to router

159.258.25.25
int gig2/2
Description uplink to switch

etc...except as strings going down the page.. i'm not sure how the formatting works on this site.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Well, I know how to append two files one to the other. I have tried using a for statement, however I don't understand this statement enough to use it for this problem. I have an Example from another script I have pieced together:

Comment: for /f %%i in (%check%) do (
    set SERVER_ADDRESS=ADDRESS N/A
    for /f "tokens=1,2,3" %%x in ('ping -n 1 %%i ^&^& echo SERVER_IS_UP') do (
        if %%x==Pinging set SERVER_ADDRESS=%%y
        if %%x==Reply set SERVER_ADDRESS=%%z
        if %%x==SERVER_IS_UP (echo %%i [!SERVER_ADDRESS::=!] is UP!) >>%OUTPUT_FILE% & echo crt.Screen.Send( "!SERVER_ADDRESS::=!>>apip.txt" 8 vbCR stumps) >>%iptest%
    )
)

Comment: If you don't understand `for statemanet` you won't find help here. You should learn some basic first.